# Hosting a web server through an virtual machine image

Tags: image, apache, webserver, vmware

Is it possible that, on my Windows machine, I get the vmware player and an ubuntu image and host a web server from that image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is very much possible. You need to configure the network settings on the virtual machine for this. The virtual server needs to be accessible from the client. This might need a Live IP or port forwarding